# Стартовая страница для незалогиненных пользователей

Tags: joomla, php

Всем салют.

Задача:
при входе на сайт на Joomla 2.5 нужно сделать стартовую страницу, на которую бы попадали все незалогиненные пользователи. На странице - форма с логином паролем.
Т.е. нужно сделать все то же самое, что делает функция "выключить сайт" в "общих настройках", но пускать на сайт не только администраторов, а любых зарегистрированных пользователей.

Есть 2 пути:

1. Исправить права доступа для зарегистрированных пользователей (чтоб их пускало при выключенном сайте) и выключить сайт.
2. Написать самому страничку с формой входа поправив index.php. 
   Я знаю php ООП, но не знаю api Joomla. 
   Подскажите, по какому пути пойти (может есть какой-то третий) и хотя бы в общих чертах реализацию.

Всем спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3. В index.php темплейта в начале дописать проверку, залогинен ли пользователь. Криво, т.к. срабатывает только при визитах на страницы, использующие темплейт. Примерно так:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
if( $user->guest) {
    // форма чтобы залогиниться
    // exit();
}
// дальше обычный темплейт
```

4. написать плагин, обрабатывающий одно из [событий](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin#Events), например, [`onAfterRoute`](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/System#onAfterRoute). В плагине надо проверить, что юзер опять же, guest, и что запрошена любая страница, кроме формы авторизации. Редиректить анонима на авторизацию.

5. Найти такой же готовый плагин.

Comment: Спасибо. Нашел совсем простое решение.
Т.к. сайт у меня не большой, просто изменил доступ ко всем пунктам меню и модулям, кроме формы входа на "для зарегистрированных". Помогло. Теперь не залогининный пользователь видит только форму входа. 
Но информация про $user = JFactory::getUser(); if( $user->guest) полезная. Буду знать.